# Twitter search method using Twitter4J

Tags: java, android, eclipse, twitter4j

I am doing an application where u write a word, a new activity opens up then all the tweets SHOULD show up, but i'm getting an error.

I am calling the method `printTweets` inside the main of the new activity:

And don't worry all my credentials work, i have tried the code on a java application ( not android) and it worked fine and I was getting results.

This is my code:

```
    public void printTweets(String q) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(layout);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxx")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxx")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxx")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxx");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        Query query = new Query(q);
        QueryResult result = null;
        do{
            try {
                result = twitter.search(query);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + tweet.getText());
            layout.addView(tv);

        }
        } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);

}
```

This is my error:

> 11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sentimentmining/com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:71)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.(HttpResponseImpl.java:34)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:141)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:81)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1929)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:306)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults.printTweets(DisplayResults.java:83)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults.onCreate(DisplayResults.java:34)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>   11-15 01:07:30.890: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    ... 11 more

If you need anything more please tell me and I will give it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException

set this permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Use asyntask

The reason why you are getting this exception is because you are attempting to perform an expensive operation on the UI thread, which can significantly slow your app down and cause it to force close. You should wrap your code in an AsyncTask (or Thread) instead.

or

use this before doing network operations

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

Comment: Hello @SHASHIDHAR MANCHU , first of all thank you for your reply it helped for a temporary solution. I was wondering if you could provide a good link for a tutorial for AsyncTask or even an example for it so I can implement it in my code.